# search for filenames in textfiles

Tags: vb.net, stringbuilder

I have a powershell script that pulls out lines containing ".html" ".css" and so forth

however what I need is to be able to strip out the entire filename

using a pattern.... the entire pattern is returned example

.........\.html returns

src="blank.html"

my answer came in VB (with a bunch of work and even more research) I wanted to share with you all the results, it's not pretty but it works. is there an easier way?

I have commented the code to help in understanding.

```
    Private Sub find()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(openWork.FileName)
    Dim a As String
    Dim SearchForThis As String
    Dim allfilenames As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim first1 As String
    Dim FirstCharacter As Integer
    'Dim lines As Integer

    SearchForThis = txtFind.Text
    Do
        a = reader.ReadLine 'reader.Readling
        If a = "" Then
            a = reader.ReadLine
        End If
        If a Is Nothing Then 'without this check the for loops run with bad data, but I can't check "a" without reading it first.

        Else
            For FirstCharacter = 2 To a.Length - SearchForThis.Length ' start at 2 to prevent errors in the ")" check
                If Mid(a, FirstCharacter, SearchForThis.Length) = SearchForThis Then ' compare the line character by character to find the searchstring
                    If Mid(a, FirstCharacter - 1, 1) <> ")" Then ' checks for ")" just before the searchstring (a common problem with my .CSS finds)
                        For y = FirstCharacter To 1 Step -1

                            If Mid(a, y, 1) = Mid(a, FirstCharacter + SearchForThis.Length, 1) Then ' compares the character after searchstring till I find another one
                                Dim temp = Mid(a, y + 1, (FirstCharacter + SearchForThis.Length) - 1 - y) ' puts the entire filename into variable "temp"
                                allfilenames.Append(temp & Chr(13)) 'adds the contents of temp (and a carrage return) to the allfilenames stringbuilder
                                y = 1
                            Else

                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If


    Loop Until a Is Nothing

    Document.Text = allfilenames.ToString
    reader.Close()

End Sub
```

(updating for comments... thanks for the input)

each line in the .css search file looks something like this.

```
addPbrDlg.html:12:<link rel=stylesheet href="swl_styles-5.0o-97581885.css" TYPE="text/css">
addPbrDlg.html:727:             html(getFrame(statusFrame).strErrorMessage).css('color','red');
```

for this I want to return

> swl_styles-5.0o-97581885.css

but not return

> statusFrame).strErrorMessage).css

basically I want to strip out the file names from HTML code
but if I use a pattern like

> .............................\.css

it would return something like

> t href="swl_styles-5.0o-97581885.css

Finally... there are some variables that I don't need to worry about (due to my personal situation) like I know that all web pages are ".html" all images are ".gif" there are ".css" and ".js" files as well that I want to pull. But because the designers are extremely consistant I know that there aren't any surprise files (.jpg or .htm) 
I can also assume that if there is a single quote after the filename, there will be a single quote before. same with double quote.

Thanks for your input so far... I appreciate your time and knowledge.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: show us an example of a complete line, and what you want to extract from the line.

Comment: you're right. I should have given an example of some search lines

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Regex` and do something like this

```
Dim files = Regex.Matches("<your whole file text>", "Your regex pattern");
```

Your `regex` pattern will look something like this "\Asrc="".+((\.html)|(\.css))"")". This is probably wrong but when you get that straight follow with

```
Dim fileList as new List(of String)
For Each file as Match in files
    ' strip " src=" " and last " " "
    fileList.Add(file.Value.Substring(5, file.Value.Length - 6))

Next
```